# How to list user roles/permission on dataset/tables in Big query including inherited roles/permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, permissions, dataset, bq

Is there any way through which we can list all the permissions on the dataset/table without using the bq console , I would like to achieve it using bq command or bq Sql.

I know through bq show 'dataset_name' we can list the roles/permissions but it doesn't show the inherited roles/permissions.